# Query to split a row into two

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a requirement to split a row into two based on the nullability of two columns in the table used in the query.

```
Sample Data
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrimaryID      SecondaryID      PassedSubject      FailedSubject     PSField       FSField
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1               11                ABC                XYZ          PSFldData1    FSFldData1
   1               12                DEF                NULL         PSFldData2    FSFldData2
   2               21                NULL               GHI          PSFldData3    FSFldData3
```

So for the above data I am looking for a possible result in the below format, the requirements being is that if the fields "PassedSubject" and "FailedSubject" columns are NOT NULL then I need to split the row in to and only PSField(PassedSubject Field) should be populated for the row containing PassedSubject value and FSField should be populated for the row containing the FailedSubject value.

```
Sample Result
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PrimaryID      SecondaryID      PassedSubject      FailedSubject     PSField       FSField
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1              11                ABC               NULL          PSFldData1    NULL
    1              11                NULL              XYZ           NULL          FSFldData1
```

I need to split the row only for the field being NOT NULL for "PassedSubject" and "FailedSubject" columns.

Comment: Can you supply the rest of sample result with id(1,12) and (2,21)?

Comment: @JaugarChang The result remains the same for the rest with id(1,12) and (2,21)

Comment: @JaugarChang Definitely I will check it!!

Comment: @JaugarChang Yes, this works perfectly !! Thanks for your efforts !! By the way can you let me know in what situations we can use Cross Apply ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT PrimaryID,
       SecondaryID,
       CR.PassedSubject,
       CR.FailedSubject,
       CR.PSField,
       CR.FSField
FROM   TableName
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
     ( PassedSubject,NULL,PSField,NULL),
     ( NULL, FailedSubject,NULL,FSField))    
  CR ( PassedSubject, FailedSubject, PSField, FSField)
WHERE TableName.PassedSubject IS NOT NULL AND TableName.FailedSubject IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE TableName.PassedSubject IS NULL OR TableName.FailedSubject IS  NULL
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/39b4d/10)</kbd>

```
PRIMARYID   SECONDARYID PASSEDSUBJECT   FAILEDSUBJECT      PSFIELD     FSFIELD
        1            11           ABC        (null)     PSFldData1      (null)
        1            11        (null)           XYZ         (null)  FSFldData1
        1            12           DEF        (null)     PSFldData2  FSFldData2
        2            21        (null)           GHI     PSFldData3  FSFldData3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH PassedCTE AS
(
    SELECT PrimaryID,
           SecondaryID,
           PassedSubject,
           NULL AS FailedSubject,
           PSField,
           NULL AS FSField
    FROM   TableName
    WHERE  PassedSubject IS NOT NULL
),FailedCTE AS
(
    SELECT PrimaryID,
           SecondaryID,
           NULL AS PassedSubject,
           FailedSubject,
           NULL AS PSField,
           FSField
    FROM   TableName
    WHERE  FailedSubject IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT * 
FROM   PassedCTE 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM   FailedCTE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that your sample result correspond to the details of what you want (none of the upper rows have been split in two as neither has secondaryId=11, but anyway what you want to do (split a row in two) can be easily achieved with an UNION ALL clause, using different criteria for the WHERE:

```
SELECT PrimaryId, SecondaryID, ....
FROM table
WHERE <condition for first line to appear>
UNION ALL
SELECT PrimaryId, SecondaryID, ....
FROM table
WHERE <condition for second line to appear>
```

Hope this helps